# Show that the elements of the LR decomposition for tridiagonal matrices T can be determined by the following recursive relation

Tags: numerical-calculus, tridiagonal-matrices, lu-decomposition

Show that the elements of the LR decomposition $ T=L R $ can be expressed by tridiagonal matrices $ T $ with

[image]
can be determined by the following recursive relation:

[image]

How could you prove this statement clearly (I don't really have any ideas)?
Then I should calculate the LR decomposition of the matrix $ T $ in the case $ n=12, b_{i}:=c_{i+1}:=-2 $ for $ i=1, \ldots, 11 $, $ a_{i}:=4 $ for $ i=1, \ldots, 12 $ - how do I do that for this general example?